# Does Deserter's Quarters get overriden by Horizon Boughs?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In a game of Planechase, suppose we're on [Horizon Boughs](http://magiccards.info/extra/plane/planechase/horizon-boughs-gateway-promo.html), which says:

> All permanents untap during each player's untap step.

I have [Deserter's Quarters](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=380397) out, tapped using its second ability to keep another creature tapped.

> You may choose not to untap Deserter's Quarters during your untap step.
>
> {6}, {T}: Tap target creature. It doesn't untap during its controller's untap step for as long as Deserter's Quarters remains tapped.

Would this mean I can choose not to untap Deserter's Quarters during the untap step, and keep the other creature tapped, or do both of them untap anyway?

Comment: I've edited your question for clarity. Do you also mean to ask if Deserter's Quarter's target of its activated ability would be untapped?

Comment: I am asking if it has to untap my opponent is saying it has to, but i believe i can choose not to untap it, which means the creature it is keeping tapped will not untap as i am keeping deserter's quarters tapped so that creature cant untap.

Comment: Ok, edited a bit more. Does that fit?

Answer (score 3):

Deserter's Quarters becomes next to useless.

If someone casts [Burst of Energy](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Burst%20of%20Energy) targeting your Deserter's Quarters, it would untap since it's not *your untap step*. Same thing here.

When in Horizon Boughs, your Deserter's Quarters untaps in the other players' untap steps since you only have the option of not untapping him in *your untap step*. (The creature held in Deserter's Quarters remains tapped.)

Similarly, the creature held in Deserter's Quarters untaps in your untap step since Deserter's Quarters only prevents it from untapping in *its controller's untap step*.

[Horizon Boughs](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Horizon%20Boughs) makes [Deserter's Quarters](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=380397) really inefficient. At best, you could retap a creature every turn for 6 mana in a two-player game.